# I need to check if CHAR from Array1 contains some CHAR from my Array2 but I cant use Contains for CHAR... How to solve it?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

I need to convert one phone number (badly written) to correct format. Example: + 420 741-854()642. to +420741854642
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAend.png)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `string result = "+" + string.Concat(source.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));`

Comment: You have it backwards, you want to check if your list of valid characters contains the character in the loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in the style you showed in the image then you can fix it by doing this:

```
        string number = "+ 420 741-854()642.";
        char[] povolene = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+' };

        for(int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++) {
            if (povolene.Contains(number[i])) {

                .
                .
                .
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you man <3.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd just Regex replace all non digits with nothing;

```
var messy = "+ 420 741-854()642";
var clean = Regex.Replace(messy, "[^+0-9]", "");
```

For the regex pattern `[^+0-9]` this means "a single character that is from, the set of: (all characters except) `+` or `0` to `9` so in practice this pattern matches the space  , hyphen `-`, parentheses `()` etc.. And any matched character (i.e. a bad character) is replaced with nothing

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for RegEx (Regular Expressions) :) you could have something like this: /+?\d+/gm which will return three matches from +420741-854()642 as ['+420741', '854', '642'] which can of course then be concatenated. You could always as well replace the '+' with '00' beforehand and just concatenate matches from /\d+/gm. This just matches all digits in the string.

https://regex101.com/ is a great resource for learning RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can *filter out digits* (`c >= '0' && c <= '9'`) with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string source = "+ 420 741-854()642.";

string result = "+" + string.Concat(source.Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
```

Comment: Or Char.IsDigit?

Comment: @Caius Jard: `Char.IsDigit` returns `true` on all *unicode* digits, (say, persian ones, `۱۲۳`), not only `0..9`

Comment: "+" should only prepended if the input string starts with "+" or "00". Because you might concat an invalid number if the country code is ommitted in the input string...

Comment: @lidqy: that's why I've started my answer as "Technically, you can...". If phone number can be in *different formats* (with or without country/region code), *invalid* an elaborated analysis is required and we have no info from the question to perform it

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yeah that's right it's outside the scope of the question, but still sth to consider if you want to validate and properly format phone numbers...